# Exercise 2 from Terry Tao blogsite on Compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I was reading the [blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/245b-notes-10-compactness-in-topological-spaces/) and trying to solve some exercises. But soon I realize I can't find any way to solve the following exercises:

> Let $X=(X,\mathfrak F)$ be a compact topological space then show that any weaker topology $\mathfrak F' \subset \mathfrak F$ on $X$ also yields a compact topological space $(X,\mathfrak F')$

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space then show that any stronger topology $\mathfrak F' \supset$ on $X$ also yields a Hausdorff topological space $(X,\mathfrak F')$.

The ultimate goal of the two exercise is to prove a compact topology cannot be strictly stronger than a Hausdorff one, and a Hausdorff topology cannot be strictly weaker than a compact one.

My main problem is, I haven't any idea to deal with stronger or weaker topology, **like without knowing the topology how could I use or say something on it.** What I am thinking now is stronger mean to assume it has more open sets and has all properties (+extra) than weaker ones. (Am I right?)

It will be great help if anyone provide a solution which will be self-contained, as I am learning this subject (topology) by my own.

Comment: Two other useful results: Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. A continuous bijection $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, i.e. $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is continuous. Corollary: If $T,T^*$ are   compact Hausdorff topologies on $X$ with $T\subseteq T^*$ then $T=T^*.$ Proof of Corollary: $id_X$ is a continuous bijection from $(X, T^*)$ to $(X,T)$ so it is a  homeomorphism so its inverse is continuous so if $U^*\in T^* $ then $U^*=(id_X)^{-1}[U^*]\in T.$

Comment: Yes, if $T,T'$ are topologies on $X $ then $T'$ is stronger than $T$ iff $T$ is weaker than $T'$ iff $T\subseteq T'.$  Strictly stronger (or weaker) means that also $T\ne T'.$

Comment: For  a function $f$ and $Y\subseteq$ domain($f$), many authors write $f(Y)$ for $\{f(y):y\in Y\}.$ This is ok provided that Y is not also  a $member$ of domain ($f)$.  Otherwise it may be ambiguous. I prefer $ f[Y]=\{f(y):y\in Y\}$. Some set-theorists write $f''Y$ for $f[Y].$ This can be confusing if you re  doing calculus.

Comment: If $T \subseteq T^*$ then how the $id_X$ from $(X,T^*)$ to $(X,T)$ is function? Like its seems obivous that $id_X^{-1}[U]\in T^*$ for all $U\in T$ as our $T$ is smaller than $T^*$ but I was wondering there are more elements in $T^*$, then how could we ensure our all elements are mapped through the identical function $id_X?$ @DanielWainfleet

Comment: When $B$ is a topology on $X$ and $C$ is a topology on $Y$ we say that a function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous from $(X,B)$ to $(Y,C)$ iff $f^{-1}V\in B$ whenever $V\in C$.  The terminology is confusing as the domain & range of $f$ are $X, Y,$ not $(X,B),(Y,C)$...$id_X $ is a  function on $X$... $id_(x)=x$ for each $x\in X$....Let $f=id_X$. Then $f$ is continuous from $(X,T^*)$ to $(X,T)$. And $f^{-1}$ is also continuous, but from $(X,T)$ to $(X,T^*).$ Therefore if $U^*$ is $T^*$-open then $f^{-1}[U^* ]$ is $T$-open. And $f^{-1}[U^* ]=U^*.$

Comment: Aha, I realize I had a wrong interpretation of the definition. Thanks, @DanielWainfleet. One last question, suppose a continuous $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\tau^*)$, now considering the pullback $\{f^{-1}(U): U\in\tau^* \}$ is a topology on $X$. Is this topology is weaker than $\tau$, if it is then why? My thought is, the pullback didn't give you all open sets which has in $\tau$.

Comment: Suppose $\tau'$ is a topology on X which is strictly weaker  than $\tau$. For example if $\tau$ is the discrete topology and $\tau'$ is not. And suppose $f:(X,\tau')\to (Y,\tau^*) $ is continuous. Then $f:(X,\tau)\to (Y,\tau^*)$ is also continuous but $\{f^{-1}U:U\in \tau^*\} \subseteq \tau'\subsetneqq \tau$.

Comment: Thank you very much @DanielWainfleet. I feel much better that you clear some of my doubt. I was learning this subject by my own. Furthermore, I realize I love analysis but couldn't come up with the solution. Any advice or roadmap or suggestion from you will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, if $\mathfrak{F}$ and $\mathfrak{F}'$ are topologies on the same set $X$, then $\mathfrak{F}'$ is weaker than $\mathfrak{F}$ if every $U$ that is open for $\mathfrak{F}'$ is also open for $\mathfrak{F}$. Equivalently $\mathfrak{F}'$ is weaker than $\mathfrak{F}$, if $\mathfrak{F}$ can be obtained from $\mathfrak{F}'$ by adding some open sets, or if $\mathfrak{F}'$ can be obtained from $\mathfrak{F}$ by removing some open sets. "Stronger" is just the converse of "weaker".

With the above in mind, look at the definition of compactness, which requires that any cover by open sets has a finite subcover. If $\mathfrak{F}'$ is weaker than $\mathfrak{F}$, then any cover by $\mathfrak{F}'$-open sets is also a cover by $\mathfrak{F}$-open sets, so if $\mathfrak{F}$ is compact, then so is $\mathfrak{F}'$. I.e., removing open sets can't change a compact topology to a non-compact one.

I'll leave you to think about the definition of Hausdorfness in these terms: you should find that adding open sets can't change a Hausdorff topology to a non-Hausdorff one.

Comment: **Adding open sets can't change a Hausdorff topology** because our previous $U,V$ s.t. $U \cap V = \emptyset$ still in there. Nice answer @Rob Arthan. You also clear my (Am I right?) portion. One last question, Is it always true that $\star$ property is folded into the stronger topological space defined on same set $X?$

Comment: Yes, that's the right approach to the Hausdorff property. I don't know what you mean by "$*$ property".

Comment: For $\star$ I mean any property like what I encounter so far was separable, first countable, second countable, Hausdorff, regular, normal etc. @Rob Arthan

Comment: You have to look at these properties case by case: a dense subset remains dense if you remove some open sets, so separability is preserved if you weaken the topology.  Comparing $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual topology and $\Bbb{R}$ with the discrete topology shows that strengthening the topology need not preserve separability or first or second countability.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\mathfrak{F}'\subseteq\mathfrak{F}$ are topologies on $X$.

An $\mathfrak{F}'$-cover of $X$ is also an $\mathfrak{F}$-cover of $X$. If $(X,\mathfrak{F})$ is compact, any $\mathfrak{F}$-cover has a finite subcover. So the given $\mathfrak{F}'$-covering has a finite subcover.

If $(X,\mathfrak{F}')$ is Hausdorff, then any two distinct points belong to disjoint members of $\mathfrak{F}'$. In particular any two distinct points belong to disjoint members of $\mathfrak{F}$; therefore $(X,\mathfrak{F})$ is Hausdorff.